# How to disable the next song key?

Tags: keyboard

I'd like to disable the next/previous song keys, because I rarely need them but often press by accident when pausing/playing. Keyboard shortcuts doesn't seem to provide a solution, and neither does googling around.

My OS X version is 10.7.1, in case it matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Function Flip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/). It can selectively toggle function keys between being regular function keys or the special hardware keys, including the media keys (F7, F8, and F9). Essentially, it does the same thing as "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" setting (System Preferences > Keyboard), except only to individual function keys instead of all of them.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. Only downside is that now I have an extra process (FFHelperApp) running in the background.